# Setting execution delay to window resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code for making my nicEdit responsive, basically making it reload on window resize so that it can take on the new dimensions:

```
$(function () {
    editor = new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'nicedit/nicEditorIcons.gif', fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('myTextarea');
})

$(window).resize(function() {
    editor.removeInstance('myTextarea'); 
    editor = new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'nicedit/nicEditorIcons.gif', fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('myTextarea');
});
```

Now I want to set an execution delay of like 0.5sec or 1sec so that my browser doesn't lag when I resize it. It lags because the `myTextarea` instance gets removed and reloaded rapidly for every pixel resized, on-the-fly.

I have tried various forms of `setTimeout(check, 1000);` on different parts of the code but couldn't figure out how to get it right.

How should I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` & `clearTimeout` to reset the timeout everytime the window starts resizing. The code in `windowResized()` will be called 500ms after the window stops resizing.

```
var windowResizeTimeout = null;

$(window).resize(function() {
            // Clears the timeout if it exists
            if (windowResizeTimeout)   clearTimeout(windowResizeTimeout);
            // Sets a new timeout
            windowResizeTimeout = setTimeout(windowResized, 500);
});

function windowResized() {
          // window resized..
          editor.removeInstance('myTextarea'); 
          editor = new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'nicedit/nicEditorIcons.gif', fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('myTextarea');
};
```

Read more about `clearTimeout()` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [debounce method](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/16/what-is-the-debounce-method-and-how-to-use-it-in-javascript) or as mentioned in the previous answers a timeout.

The debounce method :

```
/**
* Execute a function given a delay time
* 
* @param {type} func
* @param {type} wait
* @param {type} immediate
* @returns {Function}
*/
var debounce = function (func, wait, immediate) {
     var timeout;
     return function() {
         var context = this, args = arguments;
         var later = function() {
                 timeout = null;
                 if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
         };
         var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
         clearTimeout(timeout);
         timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
         if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
     };
};
```

And then use it like :

```
$(window).resize(debounce(function(){
    // the following function will be executed every half second
     editor.removeInstance('myTextarea'); 
     editor = new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'nicedit/nicEditorIcons.gif', fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('myTextarea');
},500)); // Milliseconds in which the task should be executed (500 = half second)
```

Comment: What's the advantage over simpler setTimeout approach posted by Aron?

Comment: It clears the timeout if another event is fired, otherwise you end up with multiple timeouts being set and running after each resize event.

Comment: @droprajoja Just try using the function and you'll find out by yourself. Debounce clear the previous timeout and will cause that your function is execute only once. If you test the code providen by Aron you'll see that the function is executed more than once. The answer of Sinan works in the same way debounce does, but simplified.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you've tried but try it like this

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {

        editor.removeInstance('myTextarea');
        editor = new nicEditor({ iconsPath: 'nicedit/nicEditorIcons.gif', fullPanel: true }).panelInstance('myTextarea');

    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: this will set a new timeout for every resize event that's fired causing it to redraw multiple times

Comment: You're right. Your answer is actually the correct implementation.